# 'Called id for nil' when accessing collection elements in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I've got some really weird stuff happening.
In a view, I'm populating a collection like this:

```
<% foo_options = Bar.find(f.object.bar_id).supplier_contracts.collect(&:foo).uniq.compact : [] %>
```

This is a collection of ActiveRecord models.

**EDIT:** This happens in a form, so `f.object` here refers to another ActiveRecord model instance.

If I try dereferencing the collection's elements like this on the next line:

```
<%= foo_options.first.inspect %>
```

a valid model object gets inspected.
Now, if I change it to

```
<%= foo_options.first.id %>
```

I get an exception "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4".
If I change it to

```
<%= foo_options.first.try :id %>
```

everything's OK, it displays the object's ID.
Why does the exception happen?

Comment: `f.object.bar_id` - You have an association called 'object' or am I missing something? If you do it's a really bad idea, 'object' is a reserved word in Rails and all kind of weird stuff can happen.

Comment: `f` is a form builder instance, so `f.object` references the actual model object bound to the form. Sorry for not making this clear.